# How to Enable HTTP Headers Tab in GraphiQL

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I am new to GraphQL and have built a simple API using `express` and `express-graphql`. When I run my server and go to `http://localhost:5000/graphql` in the browser I see GraphiQL and can make basic queries.

I want to set the HTTP headers of a request however. I believe there should be a `HTTP Headers` tab next to the `Query Variables` tab in the screenshot below, but for some reason it is not there.

Any ideas why it is missing or how I then set the HTTP headers of a request to my API?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In graphiql v1, you can set the `headerEditorEnabled` prop:

```js
<GraphiQL
  ref={graphiql}
  headerEditorEnabled
  fetcher={(attributes) => graphQLFetcher(attributes)}
>
```

As of v1.9.8, [`headerEditorEnabled` defaults to `true`](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/1821ef2b3f06c69fa5fa27dbd66d19e81e792590/packages/graphiql/CHANGELOG.md#198)

In graphiql v2, [`headerEditorEnabled` has been renamed to `isHeadersEditorEnabled`](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/1821ef2b3f06c69fa5fa27dbd66d19e81e792590/packages/graphiql/CHANGELOG.md#200).

Comment: Kudos, and while this is true, please note that express-graphql is no longer maintained. So I believe if the OP use express-graphql, it will still be using the old `headerEditorEnabled`. https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/main/package.json#L90